# "TypeError: tasks.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call a dictionary from Django Rest Framework API to view on my frontend. Using Django backend & Reactjs frontend. Through some research looks like i'm getting this error due to the `map()` function only accepting arrays, while my API is returning a dictionary (I THINK SO).

How do I fix this? I'm new to javascript & apologies in advance for the messy code. Please see my `App.js` below:

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            todoList: [],
        }

        this.fetchTasks = this.fetchTasks.bind(this)
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchTasks()
    }

    fetchTasks() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api-overview')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    todoList: data
                })
            )
    }

    render() {
        var tasks = this.state.todoList
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {tasks.map(function (task, index) {
                    return (
                        <div className="center-column">
                            <div className="item-row">
                                <div key={index} className="centered">
                                    <span>{task.bitcoin_symbol}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

API response:

[image]

Comment: What is `data` when the fetch has completed? I assume that it's not an array

Comment: _"returning a dictionary"_ probably not as JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries.

Comment: Knowing what `data` is, is the key to figuring this out.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks for your reply! Please see the edits above, i've included a screenshot of my Django Rest API. The DATA looked like a dictionary that's why I assumed so, but thank you for clarifying. How can i figure what DATA is?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but a screenshot isn't as useful as text. What I can see is `data` is an object. That's why there's an error. So, what property on the object would you like to map over?

Comment: @jlu You're returning a JSON. Please, show us a FULL sample what exactly gets returned from your endpoint. I'm pretty sure you're actually returning a single object which has nothing to do with any tasks and you have copied the `todoList` and `fetchTasks` from a sample learning project and trying to adapt it to your case.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I see - I don't think I've created the object to map over. Basically I have a bunch of key/ value pairs as you saw in the screenshot and I wanted to call on the key (in this case "bitcoin_symbol" and show the value ("BTC-USD") on the front-end.....I'll have to work back on the structure of this

Comment: key/value pairs is an object. You need an array to use `.map`.

Comment: @zhulien yes you are correct. I'm trying to use a sample learning project and apply it to mine

Comment: @evolutionxbox is there a way to convert this to an array?

Comment: If you could add a more complete example of the JSON being returned?

Comment: @evolutionxbox There isn't much more to the JSON being returned. It's a bunch of information I've webscraped from Yahoo Finance - in this case bitcoin_symbol, bitcoin_price, bitcoin_dailychangeinprice. I've updated the screenshot above.

Comment: Then I would ask whether mapping is even necessary?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Are there any other ways to call a key and have the value show on the frontend using react? I thought the only way to call from the backend to Reactjs frontend was by using an API

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "call" a key. `this.state.todoList.bitcoin_symbol` will return the value `'BTC-USD'`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Welp there you go, that's all I needed! I'm so sorry for overcomplicating. Thank you so much for all your help !

Comment: I'm glad I could help resolve the issue. You weren't overcomplicating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're fetching a single object, not an array. `.map()` is a method which run over **iterables**(arrays, strings, etc - objects, that can be iterated over) and creates a new output element from each input one. In react we mainly use it to convert an item to its JSX(react/html) representation. As you're working over a single object, you should access it directly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            bitcoinData = null
        }

        this.fetchBitcoinData = this.fetchBitcoinData.bind(this);
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.fetchBitcoinData();
    }

    fetchBitcoinData() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api-overview')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({
                    bitcoinData: data
                });
            );
    }

    getBitcoinRepresentation() {
        var bitcoinData = this.state.fetchBitcoinData;

        if (!bitcoinData) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div>{bitcoinData.bitcoin_symbol}</div>
                    <div>{bitcoinData.bitcoin_price}</div>
                    <div>{bitcoinData.bitcoin_dailychangeinprice}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return getBitcoinRepresentation();
    }
}

export default App;
```